# 'arp authorized' alternative

Tags: cisco, static-ip, arp, dynamic-ip

Is there another way besides arp authorized command on a cisco router to prevent users from setting static IP addresses on their computers and getting access to the network?  Essentially, limiting access to the network through a valid DHCP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[802.1x authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X) I suppose.  Other than that, or a very dynamic and clever firewall, no.